# typeorm not working in React Typescript Teams app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typeorm

I've used the [Yeoman Generator for Microsoft Teams Apps](https://github.com/pnp/generator-teams) to generate a React Typescript Nodejs personal tab application for MS Teams. This works great, and I can build nice apps that use the Teams styling, etc.

However, now I want to access data from an mssql database.
After doing some research I ended up with the typeorm ORM. However I can't get it to work.
I've added an ormconfig.json file with connection details for my db server.
And in my page I run:

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import {createConnection} from "typeorm";
import {User} from "../entities/User";

createConnection().then(async connection => {
    console.log("Inserting a new user into the database...");
    const user = new User();
    user.firstName = "Timber";
    user.lastName = "Saw";
    user.age = 25;
    await connection.manager.save(user);
    console.log("Saved a new user with id: " + user.id);

    console.log("Loading users from the database...");
    const users = await connection.manager.find(User);
    console.log("Loaded users: ", users);   
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

When I open the page in my browser to check the results (in the console) I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot read connection options in a browser context.
at e.<anonymous> (BrowserConnectionOptionsReaderDummy.js:78)
at tslib.es6.js:100
at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:81)
at tslib.es6.js:74
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at s (tslib.es6.js:70)
at e.get (BrowserConnectionOptionsReaderDummy.js:76)
at index.js:139
at tslib.es6.js:100
at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:81)
```

I understand it wouldn't be wise to have database credentials in the browser, but as I understand it, this is in fact a server-side app, running on Express.

Am I doing something wrong? (And do I understand the server-side/client-side part correctly?)

Comment: _"When I open the page in my browser to check the results (in the console)"_ This doesn't really make sense. The server should be started from the command prompt, and any server errors should appear there. The server may also provide error descriptions to the browser, but usually those don't contain stack traces. It's hard to advise more based the code you've posted, but I would double check the documentation to make sure your running this correctly.

Comment: Yes, the server is started from the command prompt, using gulp. It builds and serves the app, which can then be loaded into Teams (using Ngrok) or in the browser.
No errors appear in the command prompt.

Comment: Did you solve, I'm facing the same error. 
"Cannot read connection options in a browser context."